# LaTeX Error: File datatool-base.sty not found

Tags: glossaries, datatool

When I try to use `\usepackage{glossaries}` then I get the error message:

> "LaTeX Error: File datatool-base.sty not found".

Is something else needed?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to use the package `datatool` before using `glossaries`.

**Example:**

```
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{glossaries}
```

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to update your version of datatool. (datatool-base.sty was split away from datatool.sty in version 2.10.)

Comment: Thank you for this answer! I just read "The glossaries package: a guide for beginners" from you. It's a very good introduction!

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer would you be kind enough to provide a link to said guide?

Comment: @usernumber It's part of the `glossaries` documentation so you can just use [`texdoc`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/html/texdoc.html) (`texdoc glossariesbegin`), or you can [download it from CTAN](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Why thank you. I didn't realize that was the title of the package documentation.

Comment: @usernumber The full user manual is [`glossaries-user.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf) (`texdoc glossaries-user` or just `texdoc glossaries`) but as that covers all high-level commands it's very long and complicated (but not nearly as complicated as the documented code [glossaries-code.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-code.pdf)). "The glossaries package: a guide for beginners" (glossariesbegin.pdf) is much shorter and makes a better starting point.